# Reading a text file located on the computer with NodeMCU using Lua

Tags: lua, nodemcu, esplorer

My problem is about reading a text file (which is located in my computer) in the NodeMCU development kit. I am able to read the file content in Ubuntu terminal using a Lua script. Here I am sharing the code that I have been using for reading. Both are working pretty well in the Ubuntu terminal.

First one:

```
local open = io.open
local function read_file(path)
local file = open(path, "rb") -- r read mode and b binary mode
if not file then return nil end
local content = file:read "*a" -- *a or *all reads the whole file
file:close()
return content
```

Second one:

```
local fileContent = read_file("output.txt");
print (fileContent);

function file_exists(file)
  local f = io.open(file, "rb")
  if f then f:close() end
  return f ~= nil
end

-- get all lines from a file, returns an empty 
-- list/table if the file does not exist
function lines_from(file)
  if not file_exists(file) then return {} end
  lines = {}
  for line in io.lines(file) do 
    lines[#lines + 1] = line
  end
  return lines
end

-- tests the functions above
local file = 'output.txt'
local lines = lines_from(file)

-- print all line numbers and their contents
for k,v in pairs(lines) do
  print('line[' .. k .. ']', v)
end
```

My problem occurs when I have sent the code to NodeMCU, using Esplorer to send the code in. But the error occurs like this:

```
attempt to index global 'io' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
    applicationhuff.lua:5: in function 'file_exists'
    applicationhuff.lua:13: in function 'lines_from'
    applicationhuff.lua:23: in main chunk
    [C]: in function 'dofile'
    stdin:1: in main chunk
```

My general purpose is actually to read this datas and publish it to a Mosquitto Broker via MQTT protocol. I am new to these topics. If anyone can handle my problem it will be appreciated. Thanks for your help...

Answer (score 1):

[image]

[image]

NodeMCU does not have an `io` library. Therefore you get an error for indexing `io`, which is a nil value.

No offense, but sometimes I wonder how you guys actually manage to find your way to StackOverflow and even write some code without knowing how to do basic web research.

https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/master/en/lua-developer-faq/

> The firmware has replaced some standard Lua modules that don't align
>   well with the SDK structure with ESP8266-specific versions. For
>   example, the standard  io and os libraries don't work, but have been
>   largely replaced by the NodeMCU  node and file libraries.

https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/master/en/modules/file/

> The file module provides access to the file system and its individual
>   files.

I hope that's enough help...

Comment: Most of this answer is answering a question that wasn't asked (how to do a google search). That info would probably be better as a comment so that the answer to the question asked is easily identifiable. 
Additionally, the "I don't know what I don't know" effect may lead beginners to use ineffective google queries that seem obvious to people with more experience.

Comment: @KelsonBall I disagree. Web search might have been ineffective 10 years ago. But today I can even click on a microphone icon and ask my computer "how do I read a file in nodemcu?" and it will give me the freaking answer with examples... how is this ineffective? it also doesn't take much experience as a programmer to get that knowledge. in fact you don't even have to know google. It would be sufficient to refer to the documentation that actually comes with the development kit...

Comment: @Piglet I fully share your frustration but for whatever reason I keep going :-/

Comment: Imagine the days when we had no internet, and had to read books, docs, and talk to people :-)